# Replacing submit button with an icon on laravel forms

Tags: php, laravel, forms, font-awesome

**Question:** 
I'm using the laravel forms to make a `DELETE` request to the database, now I have a `submit` field that is included by Laravel but I want to display an icon instead.

**Code:**

```
{!! Form::open(['action' => ['TasksController@destroy', $task->id],'method' => 'POST', 'class'=> 'float-right']) !!}

    {{Form::hidden('_method','DELETE')}}
    {{Form::submit('Delete', ['class' => 'btn btn-outline-danger'])}}

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

**What I want:**

```
{{Form::submit('Delete', ['class' => 'btn btn-outline-danger'])}}

// want to replace submit field with icon

<i class="far fa-trash-alt icon-size"></i>
```

Comment: As in you want to only display the icon or you want to display the icon inside the styled button (the style being btn-outline-danger)?

Comment: Only the icon. I want to get rid of the button and make the icon act like the submit button I have in place right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this:

```
{{Form::button('<i class="far fa-trash-alt icon-size"></i>', ['type' =>'submit', 'class' => 'submit-btn'])}}
```

with style which hides the button:

```
.submit-btn {
    padding:0;
    background: none;
    border:none;
}
```

instead of:

```
{{Form::submit('Delete', ['class' => 'btn btn-outline-danger'])}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap the form with something, hide it, and submit it via js. Something like this:

```
<style>.form-wrapper>form{/*hide the form, change cursor to pointer, etc*/}</style>
<div class="form-wrapper" onclick="$(this).getElementsByTagName('form')[0].submit()">
    <i class="far fa-trash-alt icon-size"></i>
    {!! Form::open(['action' => ['TasksController@destroy', $task->id],'method' => 'POST', 'class'=> 'float-right']) !!}
        {{Form::hidden('_method','DELETE')}}
        {{Form::submit('Delete', ['class' => 'btn btn-outline-danger'])}}
    {!! Form::close() !!}
</div>
```